# How to use restricted data validation in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a following variables in a google sheet.

Google Sheet -  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19e7lLR__qfd-Lf5d1pr38ezMRvUXc_IXFuqliwMMOao/edit?usp=sharing

```
Product id  Description   Mfg. type         Value
123         Test          Warehouse         0
124         Test          Retail store      100
125         Test          Retail store      250
126         Test          Retail store  
127         Test          Warehouse
```

I have kept some data validation in `Value` column. In addition to that, I want to restrict someone that they can only choose or enter value >0 in Value column if the `Mfg. type` is `Retail Store` else we need to show some error message on pop-up to user that "You are not permitted to change the value for `Mfg. type` Warehouse".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=((C2="Warehouse")*(D2=0))+((C2="Retail store")*(D2>=0)*(D2<=250))
```

[image]